# c++ how to use class initialiser for a non default constructed class

Tags: c++, sonarlint

I started using SonarLint in VS2019 (c++17)

I can't figure out how to use a in class initialiser for a non default constructed class

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(const std::string& str);
private:
  const std::string m_foostr;
};
Foo::Foo(const std::string& str) :
m_foostr(str)
{}
```

Now the sonarlint warning pops up here

```
class Bar
{
private:
 Foo m_foo;
};

Bar::Bar() : m_foo("something) ///< this produces a warning
{
}
```

Sonarlint tells me to use in class initialiser
https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-3230

How can a achieve this?
I already tried

```
m_foo = Foo("something");
```

and

```
m_foo(Foo("something"));
```

both result in a compiler error (probably because m_foostr is const).

Could you help me out here?
Thx

**Edit**: As requested: The compiler errors are

the first one results in

```
Error C2280: attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function
```

the second one results in

```
Error 2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking N arguments
```

Comment: `both result in a compiler error`. Please include the given compilation error in the post itself. It helps a lot while comparing and finding the cause of the issue.

Comment: [Default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)?: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dc484138a691132)

Comment: If you want us to look at warning or errors you need to include them in the question.

Comment: You cannot use parenthesis to initialize a member in an in-class initializer context, you either need to use curly-braces/list initialization or the equals sign. Also, what compiler are you using? I am [unable to reproduce the compiler error either on GCC or on Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/EKEo9Td8E).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat thx that was the right hint. Using default member initialiser in the class declaration works. Thx :)

Comment: @JHeni You're missing the declaration of the constructor inside the declaration of `Bar`. If that's actually the code you're using then adding that declaration should fix the issue, no need for default member initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared default constructor. Without declaration you are writing definition, that's why you are getting first error.

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();    
private:
 Foo m_foo;
};

Bar::Bar() : m_foo("something") ///< this produces a warning
{
}
```